# docker-compose and user namespaces

Tags: docker, namespaces, docker-compose

It is known how to use user namespace with docker. Is it possible to use it with docker-compose? I mean:

```
service:
  - user-namespace: true
```

or someting like that?

Answer (score 5):

There doesn't seem to be an option to active user namespace in docker compose. There is the userns_mode property which can be used to disable user namespace using `userns_mode: "host"`

The username space feature can be [enabled on the docker deamon](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/#enable-userns-remap-on-the-daemon) which will be used by docker-compose when starting the containers.

Answer (score 4):

User namespaces are configured at the docker daemon level, not on individual containers. There's no option to opt an individual container in or out of this setting. Since `docker-compose` and `docker stack deploy` are used to configure containers and not the daemon, there's no option to configure this setting from your docker-compose.yml.